# Grepping exact value but printing entire line

Tags: grep, pattern-matching

I have a 2-column tab-separated file that I need to grep specific information from.
The file looks like this:

```
wych_hazel    agt|plt
wytensin    agt
x    agt|com|qud
xanax    agt
xtc    agt
xylocaine    agt
yellow_jacket    agt|anm
```

I need to grep from the 2nd column, those lines that ONLY have the value `agt`.

The desired output would be this:

```
wytensin    agt
xanax    agt
xtc    agt
xylocaine    agt
```

I have tried:

```
grep -e 'agt' input
```

which gives me:

```
wych_hazel    agt|plt
wytensin    agt
x    agt|com|qud
xanax    agt
xtc    agt
xylocaine    agt
yellow_jacket    agt|anm
```

then I have tried:

```
grep -oh 'agt' input
```

which gives me:

```
agt
agt
agt
agt
agt
agt
agt
```

What `grep` parameters should I introduce to arrive at my desired result?

Comment: `grep agt$ input` should do it.

Comment: @PaulR You should include your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `agt` is always at the end of the line when it's on its own then you can just do:

```
grep agt$ input
```

Comment: Note that you may want to add some conditions in front of the word itself, to prevent matching lines like "hello xxxxagt". In my answer I added `\s`, so that spaces or tabs would be required to appear before.

Comment: @fedorqui: yes, indeed - that would be more robust - I was just going for a "minimalist" solution based on the sample data provided by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

This is a job for `awk`: just tell it to look for those lines in which the second field is exactly `agt`:

```
$ awk '$2=="agt"' file
wytensin    agt
xanax    agt
xtc    agt
xylocaine    agt
```

In `grep`, you can also check the presence of a space and then end of line around `agt`:

```
grep '\sagt$' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @fedorqui I didn't think of using `awk`for this problem but it is also a great solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use word boundaries along with `-E` parameter.

```
grep -E '^[^ ]+\s+.*\sagt$' file
```